# How to get a different output if clicking on a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, checkbox, vuetify.js

I'm working on checkboxes in vuetify. My issue is how to get a different output at the second {{ selected.join() }}. If I click on the checkbox "Social Media" I'll get "On our social media" at the first {{ selected.join() }} and I want a different string (on our social media page for instance) at the second one.

````
<v-checkbox
      v-model="selected"
      label="Social Media"
      value="On our social media"
    ></v-checkbox>
    <v-checkbox
      v-model="selected"
      label="Website"
      value="on our website"
    ></v-checkbox> ```

<script>
selected: [],
</script> 
   


Output:

{{ selected.join() }}
......
{{ selected.join() }}
````

Comment: why don't you use two different variables for your v-model ?

Comment: The checkbox consists of 6 options and this way I got the issue solved I had at first with the Arrays. I did the same for radio buttons (without an array though) with  value: {'var1': "auf unseren Social-Media-Kanälen", 'var2': "auf unseren Social-Media-Kanälen aufgenommen werden"}} Hoped there would be a similar way in this case

Answer (score 0):

both checkbox v-model are binded to the same attibut `selected`
=> if you click on one checkbox, both will be updated

In addition, it is quite strange to bind a checkbox to an array, instead bind them to 2 different boolean, then you can make a computed property that return what you want based on the value of both boolean:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-checkbox v-model="checkbox1" label="Social Media"></v-checkbox>
    <v-checkbox v-model="checkbox2" label="Website"></v-checkbox>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      checkbox1: false,
      checkbox2: false,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    myWantedResult() {
      const tempArray = [];
      this.checkbox1 && tempArray.push('On our social media');
      this.checkbox2 && tempArray.push('On our website');
      return tempArray.join();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: ty, I will try it out!